# Line graph using Oxyplot Visual studio C#

Tags: c#, oxyplot

I'm struggling to get a simple line graph as an output. All tools of Oxyplot is not in my toolbar.

```
InitializeComponent();
PlotModel model = new PlotModel();

OxyPlot.WindowsForms.PlotView plot1 = new OxyPlot.WindowsForms.PlotView();     

var lineSeries = new LineSeries();
lineSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 0))
lineSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10, 4));
lineSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(30, 2));
lineSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(40, 12));
model.Series.Add(lineSeries);
```

How can I have Oxyplot commands in the toolbar in Visual Studio?

Comment: Please make it clear what your question is.

Comment: I'm not able to find any oxyplot component in my toolbox in visual studio

Comment: Is this WPF? What platform?

Answer (score 1):

### Had the same problem and finally found a solution (for WPF):

(might similarly work for WinForms)

---

1. Locate the OxyPlot DLLs in your project tree somewhere in "../packages" and copy both **OxyPLot.dll and OxyPlot.Wpf.dll** into the **same
   folder** (e. g. "../packages/OxyPlot_Wpf").
2. Then, in the solution explorer, remove the references which NuGet
   made before, and add references to the copied DLLs instead.
3. Finally, create a new tab in the Toolbox and drag OxyPlot.Wpf.dll
   from the file explorer and drop it on the created tab.

---

You should see some three dozen OxyPlot controls now.

The answer [here](https://oxyplot.userecho.com/communities/1/topics/72-no-winforms-plot-control) pointed me in the right direction.

Cheerio,
Al

Answer (score 0):

If you use WPF:

> If you want to add a Plot control in the design view, press Choose Items... in the Toolbox and browse for the OxyPlot.Wpf.dll file. If you used NuGet, it should be located in the packages folder in your solution folder.

Comment: domain is dead and link is going to wrong content, please fix or delete.